# Load large .xlsx file in python

Tags: python, dask

I want to load a large xlsx file in my jupyter notebook. Using pandas will take a lot of time, or give memory error. I have also tried dask, but I am unable to generate matplotlib and seaborn plots using the same. It is loading the whole data into memory for plotting. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried? [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)

Comment: Can't use colab. Some limitations are there on VDI. I have to run it there only. VDI has around 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: Try this! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMvT8tiHJ7o